# Careers GeoIP puts me in the wrong country

Tags: support, bug, status-norepro, jobs

Similar to: [Why does Careers list "jobs near worcester" on my homepage?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94864/why-does-careers-list-jobs-near-worcester-on-my-homepage)

On the Careers home page I am being shown a list of jobs near Chicago, US. Interesting as that is, I am in York, UK.  In the linked question I see that Careers is using GeoIP to choose the city, but I just tested myself on their [demo page](http://www.maxmind.com/app/locate_my_ip) and my location is identified correctly.

Is this maybe related to the lack of jobs in and around York?  If so, surely it should fall back to my nearest large city with available jobs (Manchester, London) rather than showing me jobs in another country.

**Update:**

Matt's comment below was spot on, and closing my VPN connection does make Careers display jobs that are near me, but I'm confused because if I visit the GeoIP demo with my VPN active it still works as expected.  Is this something I have wrong with my VPN setup, or is there an issue with Careers?  My VPN is really just to support a private svn, and shouldn't be handling web traffic.

Comment: Any chance you are using some sort of VPN?

Comment: @Matt - I am, to a server in the UK.  It's not supposed to be handling web traffic, but disabling it has fixed the issue. Why does it affect the careers page but not the page at MaxMind that I linked to above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like an odd, one-off interaction with your VPN, so unless it's causing major problems or other people are seeing it I'm going to mark it [status-norepro].