# "jobs near [location]" should always list local jobs when signed in

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, homepage

When you are logged in and you first visit the [home page](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/), the `jobs near [location]` section lists jobs local to me.

[image: local listings]

However, if you refresh the page within some unknown amount of time, it always seems to list jobs in Chicago no matter what.

[image: Chicago?]

After that unknown amount of time, the first refresh will go back to listing the local jobs again and the cycle repeats.

Shouldn't that always be listing the local jobs?  Or at least not always be listing jobs near Chicago (if it was intended to be random)?  Whichever is appropriate.  I don't live near Chicago and don't have any immediate desire to look there either.

Looks to me like some kind of caching issue combined with [this problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94864/why-does-careers-list-jobs-near-worcester-on-my-homepage).

<sub>Or is this a subtle way for you guys to be telling me that I should be looking there?  :)</sub>

Comment: Just out of curiosity for anyone looking at this, is it also listing Chicago for you too or some other constant location?

Comment: It switched to Chicago for me as well

Comment: I've noticed the same behavior.

Comment: Hmmm, appears to be resolved now and is showing local jobs now.  Will wait for an official response before putting an answer.  Hopefully it's not just me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that our proxy servers were reporting inconsistent IP addresses. I was able to reproduce it earlier in the week, but not now. I will consider it resolved and keep an eye open.

Comment: Good enough.  I'll be looking out for it too.