# I am not in Buena Park, but my VM is

Tags: bug, jobs

I am in Boulder, CO, but work on a machine in SoCal.  Careers is always suggesting jobs in LA.  Does careers use my stated location, or my IP address, or is this just a coincidence?

Comment: Related: [Why does Careers list “jobs near worcester” on my homepage?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94864/why-does-careers-list-jobs-near-worcester-on-my-homepage), [Careers GeoIP puts me in the wrong country](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109181/careers-geoip-puts-me-in-the-wrong-country)